# Total number of animals in Australia

Tags: biodiversity

In the last weeks there have been a lot of news reports about the number of animals that died in the current wild fires. However, I was wondering, what that is as a percentage of overall animal population in Australia. So:

What's the total number of animals living in Australia?

Comment: I wasn't sure about the tags, you're of course free to change it to more fitting ones

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  It would be best if you could include actual quotes from the news articles you are looking at.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that the definition of "animals" behind the "# dead in fires" numbers going around is not the same as a biologist's definition of "animal"